# Filling a 'list' of dictionaries of key-values from 'list' of data

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a 'huge' list of countries and data relevant to each of the countries as lists in python. I need to map the data to each list. Therefore after some googling, have come to use dictionaries in python for this purpose. That is, each dictionary for each country resulting in a list of dictionaries. Then populate these dictionaries with the data(keys) like capital, language and population and their corresponding values. Ultimately I should have them all as numpy array as I need to plot graph for say example, country and its population.

I am just a beginner so please feel free to suggest any better ways of doing this. Here is what I began with(reduced my dictionary to just 4) and somehow reached a dead end.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#
#Dictionary example
#


import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':

    country_names = [ 'Germany', 'Italy', 'Netherlands', 'France'] #list of countries

    capital_list =['Berlin', 'Rome', 'Amsterdam', 'Paris']#list of capitals to be mapped to countries
    population_list= ['3.5','2.1', '0.3', '2.8'] #list of population of induvidual countries, all figures in Million
    language_list=['German','Italian','Dutch','French'] #list of languages to be mapped to countries

    #dict1={"CAPITAL":xxx, "POPULATION":yyy, "LANGUAGE": zzz} ##map these data as key value pairs for each country(where each country is a      dictionary)
    dictionary_list ={ "CAPITAL": i, "POPULATION":i, "LANGUAGE": i for i in country_names}
    #dictionary_list ={ i: [] for i in country_names}

    for i in range(len(country_names)): 
        dictionary_list['CAPITAL'] = capital_list[i]
        dictionary_list['POPULATION'] = population_list[i]
        dictionary_list['LANGUAGE'] = language_list[i]
    print dictionary_list
    #for value in dict.itervalues(): ...

    #for key, value in dict.iteritems():

    #numpy array of dictionary
```

My problem is I do not see how to interatively create dictionaries and populate the keys with their values iteratively. The only fixed metric is the key (for now just 3 being population, language and capital).

Comment: Why is it a dead end? Can you clearly state your question with the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip`

**Ex:**

```
country_names = [ 'Germany', 'Italy', 'Netherlands', 'France'] #list of countries
capital_list =['Berlin', 'Rome', 'Amsterdam', 'Paris']#list of capitals to be mapped to countries
population_list= ['3.5','2.1', '0.3', '2.8'] #list of population of induvidual countries, all figures in Million
language_list=['German','Italian','Dutch','French'] #list of languages to be mapped to countries

dictionary_list = [ {"COUNTRY": country, "CAPITAL": capital, "POPULATION":population, "LANGUAGE": lang} for country, capital, population, lang in zip(country_names, capital_list, population_list, language_list)]
print(dictionary_list)
```

---

or

```
keys = ["COUNTRY", "CAPITAL", "POPULATION", "LANGUAGE"]
dictionary_list = [ dict(zip(keys,data)) for data in zip(country_names, capital_list, population_list, language_list)]
print(dictionary_list)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'CAPITAL': 'Berlin',
  'COUNTRY': 'Germany',
  'LANGUAGE': 'German',
  'POPULATION': '3.5'},
 {'CAPITAL': 'Rome',
  'COUNTRY': 'Italy',
  'LANGUAGE': 'Italian',
  'POPULATION': '2.1'},
 {'CAPITAL': 'Amsterdam',
  'COUNTRY': 'Netherlands',
  'LANGUAGE': 'Dutch',
  'POPULATION': '0.3'},
 {'CAPITAL': 'Paris',
  'COUNTRY': 'France',
  'LANGUAGE': 'French',
  'POPULATION': '2.8'}]
```

Comment: Could you pls just elaborate what exactly this zip function is doing? thanks

Comment: @tweet. Easier to understand from here https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp and https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip

Answer (score 1):

Do you want :

```
headers = ['name' , 'capital' , 'language']

arrs = [country_names , population_list, language_list]


dicts = [   { name: arr[x] for name, arr in zip(headers, arrs )} for x in range(len(country_names [0]))]
```